# tree execution in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a small DSL where user can express certain conditions for some actions. Now i need to resolve those conditions on sql server.

The nodes in condition are AND/OR/ atom, where AND/OR are binary expressions and atom is Identifier `==` Operand, with `==` being the only operator.

So i created following table in Sql Server to store the tree.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Condition]([Id] [hierarchyid], [Order] [int] NULL,
[NodeType] [nchar](10),[Identifier] [nvarchar](50) ,[Operand] [nvarchar](255) NULL)
```

Is there any way to walk this tree and eval its node in a sql statement ? I can do this in C# with compiled code, but i am stuck thinking about it in sql. I need it in sql because the filtering of data has to happen in sql.

for example if condition is

```
(T=="T1" || T=="T2") && (R=="R1" || R =="R2") || T=="T3"
```

The table will look like

```
Id      Order   NodeType   Identifier  Operand      Id.ToString() 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x      NULL     OR         NULL        NULL        /
0x58    1       AND         NULL        NULL        /1/
0x5AC0  1       OR          NULL        NULL        /1/1/
0x5AD6  1       Expr        T           T1          /1/1/1/
0x5ADA  2       Expr        T           T2         /1/1/2/
0x5B40  2       OR          NULL        NULL       /1/2/
0x5B56  1       Expr        R           R1         /1/2/1/
0x5B5A  2       Expr        R           R2         /1/2/2/
0x68    2       Expr        T           T3         /2/
```

Comment: Could you post an example “condition” and corresponding table records?

Comment: @DourHighArch please see updates

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know the values of the terms until we evaluate them, we need to do this from the bottom up. In code, we have a stack that can keep track of where we are. I didn't really want to build a stack, so I evaluated all the terms from the bottom up.

I tried to do this with a CTE, but failed. I couldn't get both of the terms in the recursive member of the CTE. Hence, I had to write my own loop.

There's a table holding all the intermediate values `@I`. Each loop we get closer to the top of the tree. When we have the value of the root node, we are done. We'll also be clearing out the unnecessary rows so that at the end, we just have one row.

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Condition](
  [Id] hierarchyid,
  [Order] [int] NULL,
  [NodeType] [nchar](10),
  [Identifier] [nvarchar](50),
  [Operand] [nvarchar](255) NULL);

insert Condition (id, "Order", NodeType, Identifier, Operand) values
(0x, null, 'OR', null, null),
(0x58, 1, 'AND', null, null),
(0x5ac0, 1, 'OR', null, null),
(0x5ad6, 1, 'Expr', 'T', 'T1'),
(0x5ada, 2, 'Expr', 'T', 'T2'),
(0x5b40, 2, 'OR', null, null),
(0x5b56, 1, 'Expr', 'R', 'R1'),
(0x5b5a, 2, 'Expr', 'R', 'R2'),
(0x68, 2, 'Expr', 'T', 'T3');
```

Here's the code assuming that `@T` and `@R` are the identifiers we are looking at:

```
declare @T varchar(max) = 'T1';
declare @R varchar(max) = 'R1';

declare @I table (
  id hierarchyId,
  "order" int,
  value bit
  );

insert @I (id, "order", value)
select id, "order", case when operand = 
      case when identifier = 'T' then @T when identifier = 'R' then @R end 
      then 1 else 0 end
from condition
where nodetype = 'Expr';

while not exists (select * from @I where id = 0x) begin
  insert @I (id, "order", value)
  select node.id, node."order", 
    case
      when nodetype = 'AND' then
        case when L.value = 1 and R.value = 1 then 1 else 0 end
      when nodetype = 'OR' then
        case when L.value = 1 or R.value = 1 then 1 else 0 end
    end
  from condition node
  join @I L on L.id.GetAncestor(1) = node.id and L."order" = 1
  join @I R on R.id.GetAncestor(1) = node.id and R."order" = 2

  delete from @I where id.GetAncestor(1) in (select id from @I)
end


select *, id.ToString() from @I
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e5cc/1